# Why close this question?

Tags: discussion

The following question has two close votes for the "opinion" reason.  What?  How is a most-used app an opinion?

In other words why is this bad
[What Android app is most-used for reading music on the bandstand in these circumstances?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22051/what-android-app-is-most-used-for-reading-music-on-the-bandstand-in-these-circum)

but this is good
[Learning the guitar from basics](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22076/learning-guitar-from-basics)
?

Comment: Links would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine because it is a question that has no single answer, which makes it not very suitable on stack exchange.

Comparing number of close votes or downvotes with another question is generally not constructive. Sometimes people will not see a question, sometimes the wording is different enough that one works and one doesn't, etc.

Comment: How is it different from this question? http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22076/learning-guitar-from-basics

Comment: That question should also be closed, for a similar reason. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: What about starting a community wiki in both questions instead of closing them? Something similar happened here: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/glossary-of-guitar-effects